# Can I deploy an app that uses both Python and Node.js on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

*See TL;DR before the question if you wish, but any quick responses are appreciated.*

---

I have a web-app that uses Node.js for the backend and Python for running a particular script.

The app basically takes an MS Excel file, does some computations on it (here is where Python comes into play) and returns the result MS Excel file.

I've used Python successfully along with Node.js using the `child_process` class in Node.js.
I've also deployed the app on Heroku using [Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) . (I've added both Python and Node.js buildpacks in order for it to work.)

Now, the slug size limit of Heroku is a problem for me as my Python program (which is basically an ML model) uses resources more than 300mb (around 13.8k individual files). Before someone points it out, I cannot use S3 in this case as my Python script needs to **read and use** the files (which are the parameters for the ML model) from a folder.

So, I thought of moving to AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I haven't been able to find out any features analogous to Heroku buildpacks. Is there any way I can make it work?

---

#### TL;DR

***I want to deploy an app that uses Node.js along with Python with some (heavy) dependencies.
Can I do that? If yes then how? Are there any features like [Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)?***

Any detailed pointers are welcome.

Thank you =)

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Not really, I remember not using EBS.